# LINQ Join 2 Datatables and With SUM AND GROUP BY

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by, sum

I simply can not get this to work out at all, so any expert help would be very much appreciated.

I'm trying (as the subject suggests) to join 2 datatables on Zip Code, but return a table which grouped this by State and has a SUM() of sales.

Here's the latest version of my troubles:

```
var results =(
    from a in dtList.AsEnumerable()
    join b in dtListCoded.AsEnumerable()
    on a.Field<string>("ZIP") equals b.Field<string>("zip") 
    group a by {a.Field<string>("StateCode")} into g
    select new { 
       StateCode = a.Field<string>("StateCode"),
       SumSales = b.Sum(b => b.Field<double>("SUMSales"))
    });
```

I can join the 2 tables but its getting the result i need that seems to be the tricky bit. If need be I will just have to do 2 queries, but that just seems a bit backward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, CatchingMonkey!  I have a similar question.  The answer by Kaido does not contain enough detail for me.  My question is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/43766663/1735836.  Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two queries wouldn't be any slower (they should be brought together into a single SQL query upon execution), and would be a lot more readable, transparent during debugging and reusable. I'd recommend breaking it down.

Comment: Hey, Kaido! Your answer does not contain enough detail for me. I have a similar question.here: stackoverflow.com/q/43766663/1735836. Can you help me out?